# First countability of $[0,1]^\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, first-countable, box-topology

The proofs I know for the fact that the space $[0,1]^\mathbb{R}$ is not first countable, use the product topology in some step of the demonstration. ([Reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/787682/680679))

So, I would like to know if this space is also not first countable in the box topology and also if there is any topology that makes this space first countable.

Edit:
As Brian commented in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4027203/680679), I was looking for a topology that was different from the trivial and the discrete.

Comment: The trivial topology, for one.

Comment: @ElliotG Yes.... Except this topology....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s even easier to show that it’s not first countable in the box topology than it is to show that it’s not first countable in the product topology: even $[0,1]^{\Bbb N}$ isn’t first countable in the box topology.

There are many first countable topologies that can be put on the set $[0,1]^{\Bbb R}$, including the trivial and discrete topologies, but I expect that you want one that is directly related to the structure of the product. Any metrizable topology will work, and there is a natural metric on it: for $x,y\in[0,1]^{\Bbb R}$ let

$$d(x,y)=\sup\{|x_r-y_r|:r\in\Bbb R\}\,.$$